# undefined reference to `func()'

Tags: c, linux, undefined-reference

I'm making some change to an existing linux c project.

In `/vobs/ua/HDL/VHDL/CmdUtil/src/help.c`, I define func like this:

```
void func(){
...
}
```

In file `/vobs/ua/HDL/Interface/cli/src/cliSystem.C`, I write this code:

```
extern void func();
...
void func1(){
  ...
  func();
  ...
}
```

In file `/vobs/ua/HDL/VHDL/DsnMgr/src/shell.c`, I write this:

```
extern void func();
...
void func2(){
  ...
  func();
  ...
}
```

In file `/vobs/ua/HDL/VHDL/DsnMgr/src/shell.c`, I write this:

```
extern void func();
...
void func2(){
  ...
  func();
  ...
}
```

In file `/vobs/ua/HDL/VHDL/lib2v/src/asicLibCells.C`, I write this:

```
extern void func();
...
void func3(){
  ...
  func();
  ...
}
```

I didn't declare func in any header files.

The problem is, for the call to func in vobs/ua/HDL/Interface/cli/src/cliSystem.C and /vobs/ua/HDL/VHDL/lib2v/src/asicLibCells.C, there is error

> undefined reference to `func()'

But for `/vobs/ua/HDL/VHDL/DsnMgr/src/shell.c`, there is no error.

After I declare `func` in  `vobs/ua/HDL/Interface/cli/src/cliSystem.C` and `/vobs/ua/HDL/VHDL/lib2v/src/asicLibCells.C` like this:

```
extern "C" void func();
```

There is no error in `/vobs/ua/HDL/VHDL/lib2v/src/asicLibCells.C`, but the error in `vobs/ua/HDL/Interface/cli/src/cliSystem.C` persists.

What's wrong? What can I do to eliminate this error?

Comment: Do you include the header files in both files? I think you only include it in shell.c.

Comment: Why do you keep your filenames in fUnKY caPS? Very strange-looking casing there ...

Comment: Please show the commands you are using to compile and link the code.

Comment: Using upper-case `C` as the source file suffix indicates that it is a C++ source file. Is that truly the case? If you're programming in C then rename the file to have a lower-case `c` suffix instead.

Comment: Show the code with `include`s -  in which `.c` files you're including `.h` files

Comment: Yes, cpp source file@Someprogrammerdude

Comment: just to show it's a function@unwind

Comment: The header files included in this 2 files are different, but I didn't declare func() in any header files.@Larce@Rogus

Comment: It's a good idea to avoid using upper case C to denote a C++ file. You tend to get into a terrible mess when you try to port the code to Windows or macOS where `foo.c` and `foo.C` are the same file.

Comment: There is never ever a reason for you to write `extern void func()` in a C or C++ file, this is always bad program design. Use header files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the function `func` is a C function, and you try to call it from a C++ function. This is problematic because C++ does something called [*name mangling*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling) to allow things like function overload.

That means when you do your declaration

```
extern void func();
```

the C++ compiler will *mangle* the symbol and that mangled symbol will not be found.

In C++ you have to inhibit this name mangling for functions that comes from C object files. This is done with a special `extern` declaration:

```
extern "C" void func();
```

---

On a slightly related note, in C a declaration like

```
void func();
```

doesn't mean that the function takes no arguments like it does in C++. In C that declaration means that `func` takes an unspecified number of unspecified arguments. In C you *must* use `void` to declare a function that takes no arguments:

```
void func(void);
```

Comment: For /vobs/ua/HDL/VHDL/lib2v/src/asicLibCells.C, I did what you said and there is no error, but for /vobs/ua/HDL/Interface/cli/src/cliSystem.C, the error persists.

Comment: @YuanWen How do you link all the files together? How do you *build* these files? Are you building many different applications from the source files, or are you linking them (or their object files) into a single executable?

Comment: I'm not very sure, but it looks like codes under directory /vobs/ua/HDL/Interface will generate different exes with /vobs/ua/HDL/VHDL

Comment: @YuanWen Well all programs using the `func` function of course needs to link with the object file containing `func`.

Comment: Ok, so to solve the problem, I can define func under  /vobs/ua/HDL/Interface. But this leads to duplicate codes. What's the better solution.

Comment: @YuanWen How about creating a library of the code from `/vobs/ua/HDL/VHDL/CmdUtil`? Then all applications that needs functions from that library links with it?

Answer (score 1):

C++ has a thing called name mangling so that you can overload functions. If you are compiling code as C++, the declaration

```
extern void func(void);
```

will add extra characters to its name to encode the fact that it has no parameters. You can disable this by telling the C++ compiler to use C conventions:

```
extern "C" void func(void);
```

or

```
extern "C" {
    void func(void);
}
```

It's normal, however to put these in a header that can be included from both C and C++ files:

```
#if defined __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

    void func(void);
    // other function declarations

#if defined __cplusplus
}
#endif
```